# CA1026 -- Can this message be suppressed if an alternate, CLS Compliant method is supplied in place?

Tags: .net, fxcop, suppress-warnings, cls-compliant, default-parameters

According to [CA1026: Default parameters should not be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182135(VS.100).aspx) I'm not supposed to use default parameters.

MSDN says not to suppress the message:

> Do not suppress a warning from this
>   rule.

However, I wonder... if I include a CLSCompliant variation of the method, can I suppress this message? Or is having 2 variations of the same method, one with all default parameters, one empty, going to cause issues?

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
        : this(0)
    {
    }

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1026:DefaultParametersShouldNotBeUsed")]
    public Foo(Int32 id = 0)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Would that be an ok situation to ignore MSDN's suggestion? I'm clearly marking the method (constructor) as `CLSCompliant(false)` and providing a method (constructor) that does not take any default values.

---

A side note: it seems that this is in place because:

> The compiler ignores the values of
>   default parameters for Managed
>   Extension for C++ when it accesses
>   managed code.

... so, I wonder if I compile this way will that cause issues since I technically now have 2 constructors that can take 0 parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't have 2 constructors without arguments.  The default value is consumed only at compile time, and a compiler that supports default parameter values will usually also have a rule for resolving which method to target.

That said, why are you bothering to specify a default value given that you have an override without the parameter?  The main reason folks like default parameter values is that they don't want to have to bother writing the overloads.

Comment: Not sure how to get around the Microsoft FxCop warning there then. MSDN states not to suppress the message, but to fix it. I tried to find a middle ground... which is, have one method be parameterized, marked as `CLSCompliant(false)` and then offer up non-parameterized methods... mainly just one that feeds in default values. Then again, perhaps I need to rethink how to do this...

Comment: Simply removing the default value would address the FxCop violation with no loss of functionality to callers.

Comment: If a method call exists which can satisfy a call site without using default parameters, the default parameters will be ignored.  If none exists and a language supports default parameters, they'll be used.  If a language doesn't support default parameters, the compiler will squawk *and it will be necessary for the caller to specify the desired values at the call site*.  I don't see how having default parameters is detrimental to callers using languages that don't support them; the callers will simply have to write the same code that would be necessary if the defaults weren't specified.

Comment: @supercat: There's actually a bigger problem with default parameters than the rule documentation mentions.  They're handled the same way as constants by the compiler (see, for example, http://haacked.com/archive/2005/01/01/HowConstantAreYourConstants.aspx/), which means that they are not really suitable for use in truly public APIs.

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu: They are suitable for use in public APIs in those cases, and only those cases, where parameters have one clear right "default" value and there is no plausible reason why the default might need to change at some future time.  For example, if a convert-to-string method can accept an `IFormatProvider` but will use a default if passed `null`, then `null` would be a reasonable default for that parameter.

Comment: @supercat: Not necessarily...  For example, the real default behind a `null` value for an `IFormatProvider` parameter is usually `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` for BCL formatting methods (although these are implemented as overloads, not using default parameter values). While MS is unlikely to ever change those particular defaults due to backward compatibility concerns, the same may not hold true for other APIs.  Also, it's worth keeping in mind that, even if there are a few cases where a constant or default parameter value is acceptable, the general rule is still valuable, at least as a warning.

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu: The issue with default values stems solely on the possibility of the values themselves changing--not their meaning.  Given `foo(int)` with a default of 42, `foo()` will be equivalent to `foo(42)`.  If the default is changed to 23, and the *called* code is recompiled but the *calling* code isn't, `foo()` will still pass 42 rather than 23.  The only problem with using `null` as a default is that it is doesn't allow any non-default meaning to be attached to `null`.